# How to make an URL be activated when clicking on a li element with onclick? [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html-lists, element

**My Problem...** 
So I have a side bar being created from a JavaScript function and I want to add an onclick element which activated upon the li element being clicked. This is what I have but I don't know how to correct it.

```
var theArray = [{'name': 'Home', 'url': 'EverythingPrg.html'}]

window.onload = function () {
$(function () {
    for (var obj in theArray) {
        $('#theUl').append($("<li/>", {'onclick:location.href': theArray[obj].url}).append($("<a/>", {'html': theArray[obj].name})));
    }
})
```

The side bar does show, but upon clicking nothing happens...

Comment: can you create a working and verifiable (so that we can replicate the issue) snippet using `<>`?

Comment: the format for your property seems incorrect, try with `.append($("<li/>", {onclick : "location.href = '" + theArray[obj].url + "';"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this for loop to be able to work as it you need

```
for (var obj in theArray) {
    $('#theUl').append($("<li onclick=location.href='"+ theArray[obj].url + "' ></li>").append($("<a/>", {'html': theArray[obj].name})));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did work and you helped me out A LOT! This is also why you win the answer mark :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably a scope issue - you're telling it to use `obj` onclick but that doesn't exist in the scope of the click event.

Try creating the li as a jquery object and attaching the event through a jquery event bind (`.on`).

Another change I suggest is `for (var obj in theArray) {` is bad form. If the array prototype is altered, this code will fail. Instead, just increment a counter.

```
var theArray = [{'name': 'Home', 'url': 'EverythingPrg.html'}]

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
            var obj = theArray[i],
                li = $('<li>').html('<a>' + theArray[obj].name + '</a>');

            li.on('click', function() {
                window.location.href = theArray[obj].url;
            });

            $('#theUl').append(li);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your remark on array and its prototype is right, however, even if your code probably works as a workaround, the scope is not the problem here. You can set an onclick attribute directly at creation, but the format he used for this is not valid

Comment: @Kaddath Truthfully I've never used the syntax he is for setting attributes in jQuery, I just picked up on `theArray[obj].url` being referenced in the onclick but as part of an object, not concatonated into the attribute.

Comment: Yes, you are right for the concatenation too. For setting attributes at creation, you just use an object, like in my comment to main question

Comment: Yes, everything said here is true, unfortunately this was not the answer I wanted although, still thank you for the time you spend to make the solution.